# Duplicates in one list to a new list

Tags: list, f#

I have this function that takes one lists and checkes for duplicates, if any duplicates are found they are added to a new list like this:

```
let foo1 z list = list |> List.filter (fun e -> e <= z)
```

this gives foo1 1 [2;3;4;1;5;1;6;1] => [1;1;1]
the problem is that I don't want to use any of the builtin functions in f#

Comment: Is it a homework? What have you tried so far?

Comment: @bytebuster I did the function in the question, it's not a homework I am trying to understand how the different inbuilt function works and I need a good example for this one

Comment: Are you aware that the entire F# compiler + libraries are open source and on github at https://github.com/fsharp/fsharp

Comment: Your function doesn't do what you think it does. Try this: `foo1 2 [1;3;4;2;5;2;6;2]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You asked a number of basic F# questions on list processing already, so I recommend reading some introductions first and trying it yourself.

- [Working with Functional Lists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh297099%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) explains how F# lists work
- Introduction to F# has a [tutorial on lists](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_introtofsharp_topic5#_Toc281930836) and [pattern matching with recursion](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vs2010trainingcourse_introtofsharp_topic6#_Toc281930838)

Using built-in functions is the right way to solve the problem in practice. If you want to learn F# and understand recursion, then read the above first. Then you should be able to write something like:

```
let rec duplicates z = function
  // If the list is empty, return empty list of duplicates
  | [] -> []
  // If it starts with 'z' then return one duplicate and recursively process the rest
  | x::xs when x = z -> x::(duplicates x xs)
  // If it starts with something else, then skip the first element and process the rest
  | x::xs -> duplicates z xs
```

There are many F# introductions that explain how `filter` and similar functions are implemented. The [F# wikibook covers this topic](http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/F_Sharp_Programming/Lists#Filter_A_List) and you'll find it in most of the F# books (see [a list on fsharp.org](http://fsharp.org/about/learning.html)) and [Working lists](http://www.tryfsharp.org/Tutorials.aspx#) section on www.tryfsharp.org covers this too.

Comment: thanks for the reading tips, I definetly know what to do this afternoon.